# Is the complement of a symmetric relation symmetric?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory, relations

My assignment asks us to prove or provide a counter example for

**If R is symmetric, then Rc
is symmetric.**

I know that if R is symmetric, then (x,y) and (y,x) are both in R, but what I do not understand is what is R^c, what does R^c do to the relation? I believe that complement basically means "not", so does that mean the complement of R is **NOT** symmetric?

I can't seem to wrap my head around this concept, any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

A relation is usually implemented as a set of ordered pairs. Equality on $\mathbb{N}^{\geq 1}$, for instance, is implemented as $E = \{ (1,1), (2,2), (3,3), \dots \}$.

So the complement would be $$\{ \text{ordered pairs} \} \setminus E$$
That is, $$\{(1,2), (1,3), \dots, (2,1),(2,3), \dots\}$$

Suppose $R^C$ were not symmetric.
Then there would be $(a,b)$ in $R^C$ such that $(b,a)$ is not in $R^C$.
But for $(b,a)$ not to be in $R^C$ means just that $(b,a)$ is a pair which lies outside the complement of $R$ viewed as a set of ordered pairs; that is, it lies in $R$ viewed as a set of ordered pairs, and hence in $R$.
Therefore by $R$'s symmetricity, $(a,b)$ must also lie in $R$, and this is a contradiction.